# DAX Alternate function for TOP SQL statement

Tags: powerbi, dax, etl, business-intelligence, daxstudio

We use this SQL statement for getting top data value in a column

```
SELECT TOP 1 NOTE_DETAIL 
FROM CLAIM_NOTES 
WHERE CLAIM_NO = C.CLAIM_NO AND ISNULL(DELETED, 0) = 0 
ORDER BY CREATED_DATE DESC
```

How we can we use this approach in a DAX query if we want `last_note` from note detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your data:

[image]

The DAX measure:

```
Last Note Detail =
VAR MaxCreatedDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( CLAIM_NOTES[CREATED_DATE] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( CLAIM_NOTES, CLAIM_NOTES[CLAIM_NO] )
    )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( CLAIM_NOTES[NOTE_DETAIL] ),
        CLAIM_NOTES[CREATED_DATE] = MaxCreatedDate
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Gives a visual of:

[image]

Comment: but this measure is quite slow , how can we handle this issue